# How to prevent running program on Win or Unix via command line

Tags: windows, unix, command-line, phpmyadmin

After a long research here on Stackoverflow and on net I didn't found nothing talking about it. As the title say, how can I do that?

For example: I am owner of a hosted website that allow me to manage the database via PhpMyAdmin. When I try to connect to my database via prompt, the connection never go fine. It could be because of OS settings (right?).

How can I do that (in both OSs).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried connecting over SSH first? Also, do you want to prevent a programm to be run from the command line? Or you want to understand why can't you connect to your hosted DBMS from the command line?

Comment: Hello Havelock, thanks for your reply. Well, in that case I would like to know both. So how to prevent starting a MySql client session via command line and, as I'm trying just in this moment, why I can't start a MySql client session on my website's database hosted by my actual provider.

Which are the same thing I guess :)

I'm on Win and my hosted database is on a Linux machine. I'm trying to start a connection with my prompt by specifying all possible command solutions but I always receive the (common issued and posted on net) "ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect... (10060)".

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Maybe I got it. It is possible that the provider has set "bind_address" to "127.0.0.1" so nobody can connect remotely on mysql (so no connections via command line). But in this way, "in house" connections are possible (phpmyadmin, on the website itself).

I'll be waiting for confirmations (or not).

Comment: @wartoverflow yes, that is true, and there are also other ways to prevent remote connections. In the case of mysql you can also limit a user to an ip address.

Comment: Perfect guys. So I assume that the provider has set up this environment variable (due to the fact I can't verify it).

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly:

You have a website with a MySql database hosted on your providers servers.

When you try to use your local PC installation of MySql from a command prompt, it will not let you connect.

I use dreamhost.com and have a similar setup.  If I want to use database tools from my local PC to connect to the database, I have to enter my IP address in the db configuration page under "allowed hosts".

Restricting remote database connections to specific IP addresses protects your database from random hacking attempts.

As for your question about restricting command line execution of a program, that is usually just caused by missing configuration information in the environment variables - leaving the path to the executable out of the PATH variable is a common one.  You would still be able to run the program if you enter the full path to it.

It really depends on the error message you get when trying to run the program from the command line.